# WildFly 18.0.1.Final - Error fetching WildFly component 'org.picketlink:picketlink-api:::2.5.5.SP12-redhat-00006'

Tags: gradle, wildfly, picketlink

Provision worked fine with WildFly: 16.0.x - 17.0.1.

Upgraded provision.gradle to upgrade to use wildFly 18.0.1.

```
plugins {
    id "org.wildfly.build.provision" version '0.0.11'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name 'jboss-nexus'
        url "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

provision {
    // Optional destination directory:
    destinationDir = file("wildfly-as/18.0.1.Final")

    configuration = file('wildfly-server-provisioning.xml')

    // Define variables which need replacing in the provisioning configuration!
    variables['wildfly.version'] = '18.0.1.Final'

    variables['hibernate-orm.version'] = '5.3.7.Final'
    variables['hibernate-search.version'] = '5.11.0.Final'
    variables['hibernate-ogm.version'] = '5.4.1.Final'
}
```

Causes in:

> MacBook-Pro:GoStopHandle NOTiFY$ gradle provision -b provision.gradle
>
> > Configure project :
> >
> > Task :provision FAILED Error fetching WildFly component 'org.picketlink:picketlink-api:::2.5.5.SP12-redhat-00006' from
> >     configured repositories; check your repository configurations to
> >     prevent this problem. Attempting to resolve this by enabling
> >     additional repositories automatically! Adding: [mavenLocal(),
> >     mavenCentral() and
> >     http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/]
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':provision'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration67'.
>   >     Could not find org.picketlink:picketlink-api:2.5.5.SP12-redhat-00006.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s 1 actionable task: 1 executed

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted SDK 14 and 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/'.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add http://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/ as repository.

Comment: Fixed the other day. I only use 'gradle'.  I fixed it by deleting SDK 14 and 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/'. All working. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.